# JupyterNotebook / JupyterLab: How to automatically rerun a cell in case of an error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have a block of code that processes a lot of data and takes quite a while (~4 hours - I want to run it overnight). One of the methods used in a library (selenium) returns an error in around 10% of the cases when it is appealed and it requires a rerun of the block of code/cell (inconsistency with the site that is web **scraped**).

I have found a way to restart the block without losing the progress made on the processed data, however, I have to manually check for the error and rerun the cell when it happens. My question is, can this be done automatically without losing the local variables?

A simplified version of the code:

code cell 1:

```
#code
n = 0
```

code cell 2 - that can potentially return an error:

```
for i in list[n:]:
    n += 1
    #code
    method_that can return an error
    #code
```

Is there a way to restart the 2nd code cell without losing the variables stored?

Comment: you can use try and except. when the error occurs, execution moves to except block and the loop continues

Comment: It works for what I am trying to achieve - I don't know why I haven't thought of that :). Thank you!